# Free jqGrid loaded with predefined search and further search behaviour

Tags: jquery, search, free-jqgrid

Grid definition:

```
$grid.jqGrid({
        url:'xtras/Products.php',
        editurl:'xtras/Products.php',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype:'POST',
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'Catalogue',index:'catalogue.Catalogue', width:100, editable:true},
            {name:'Artist',index:'catalogue.Artist', width:170,align:"left", editable:true},
            {name:'Title',index:'catalogue.Title', width:200,align:"left", editable:true},
        ...
        ],
        postData: {
            filters: JSON.stringify({
                groupOp: "OR",
                rules: [
                    { field: "Catalogue", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" },
                    { field: "Artist", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" },
                    { field: "Title", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" }
                ]
            })
        },
        search: true,
        .....
}).jqGrid("navGrid", pagerIdSelector, {add: false, edit: false, refreshstate: "current"},
            {},{},{},
            {multipleSearch:true, sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn','ge','le','lt','gt'], showQuery: false}, {})
```

Where $search is

```
$search  = @htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['search']));
```

This works fine with search defined or not.
However, after the grid loaded and if I want to perform a new search, when I open Search box it looks like this (I was expecting Catalogue, Artist, Title..):
[image]

At this point - if I'm trying to redefine *shown* dropdowns - the search will be performed on already predefined text instead of starting a new search.

It will only perform a search from scratch if I first delete all the selects then add a new select by pressing +

How can I either:
Redefine search from the given selects OR Reset all selects in the Search box after search box is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the searching option `loadDefaults` with default value `true`. It informs jqGrid to load the filter from `postData.filters`. If I correctly understand your problem then you should just include the option `loadDefaults: false` near to `multipleSearch:true`.

By the way I find difficult to read `navGrid` parameters because of large number of parameters with the values `{}`. Free jqGrid allows to define `searching` **option of jqGrid** with the same searching options which you could use in `navGrid` or `filterToolbar`. If allows to reduce the number of parameters of `navGrid`. Additionally free jqGrid can *create* the div for the pager if you would use `pager: true` and you can skip the pager parameter in `navGrid`, `inlineNav` and `navButtonAdd`. In other words you can rewrite your code to the following

```js
$grid.jqGrid({
    url:'xtras/Products.php',
    editurl:'xtras/Products.php',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype:'POST',
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'Catalogue',index:'catalogue.Catalogue', width:100},
        {name:'Artist',index:'catalogue.Artist', width:170},
        {name:'Title',index:'catalogue.Title', width:200},
    ...
    ],
    cmTemplate: {editable: true},
    postData: {
        filters: JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "OR",
            rules: [
                { field: "Catalogue", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" },
                { field: "Artist", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" },
                { field: "Title", op: "cn", data: "<?php echo $search; ?>" }
            ]
        })
    },
    search: true,
    searching: {
        multipleSearch: true,
        loadDefaults: false,
        sopt: ['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn','ge','le','lt','gt'],
        showQuery: false
    },
    navOptions: { add: false, edit: false, refreshstate: "current" }
    .....

}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

Comment: HI Oleg! Yes that worked. For `navGrid`, however, I now have two "+" - one brings a pop up form to add, another one creates a new line for inline edit. I have additional definitions for inline edita plus I have custom "copy" button:`.jqGrid("navGrid")
  .jqGrid("inlineNav", pagerIdSelector, { editParams: editOptions, addParams: {addRowParams: editOptions}})
  .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pagerIdSelector, {
   caption: "",
   title: "Copy selected row",
   id: $grid[0].id + "_ilcopy", .... 
  });` - shall I post this as a different question?

Comment: @Elen: Do you included `navOptions: { add: false, edit: false }` option like in my answer? If "not" then you can use `.jqGrid("navGrid", {add: false, edit: false})` and `.jqGrid("inlineNav", { ...})` and `.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", { caption: "", title: "Copy selected row", id: $grid[0].id + "_ilcopy", });`. It'll fix the problem with two "+" buttons. Additionally I recommend you to use `inlineEditing: editOptions` and remove unneeded options of `inlineNav`. In any way you don't need to use `pagerIdSelector` parameter.

Comment: Yes I tried to use: `navOptions: { add: false, edit: false, refreshstate: "current" },inlineEditing: {
   keys: true,
   url: 'xtras/Products.php',
   editParams: editOptions, 
   addParams: {addRowParams: editOptions}
  },` - but I get no "+" button at all. Same with just `inlineEditing: editOptions,`

Comment: @Elen: The options `add: false, edit: false` in `navOptions` set defaults for both `navOptions` and `inlineNav`. If you use the option then you should include  `add: true, edit: true` in `inlineNav`. Alternatively you can reduce `navOptions` to `navOptions: { refreshstate: "current" }` and to use `.jqGrid("navGrid", {add: false, edit: false})` and `.jqGrid("inlineNav")`.

Comment: thank you!! I used the second method as it's easier to read/understand

Comment: @Elen: You are welcome! I think that I should add Boolean `add` and `edit` options to `inlineEditing`. The option could be used to overwrite the setting `navOptions: { add: false, edit: false }`, but only for `inlineNav`. Alternatively I could add additional Boolean `inlineAdd` and `inlineEdit` options to `navOptions`: `navOptions: { add: false, inlineAdd: false, edit: true, inlineEdit: false }`. I'm not sure which way would be better, probably the last one because we want specify the options of *navigator bar* only. What do you think about?

Comment: well if you're asking my humble opinion =) ... My intuitive action would be to check if `inlineNavOptions:` exist? So for both form and inline options enabled, my grid would look like this: `$grid.jqGrid({colModel:[....], navOptions: {add: true, edit: true, refreshstate: "current" }, inlineNavOptions: {add: true, edit: true}, Editing: FormEditOptions, inlineEditing: InlineEditOptions, ...}).jqGrid("navGrid").jqGrid("inlineNav");`, where I can use different EditOptions for form edit and inline, or the same for both. Makes sense?

Comment: this way it is understandable navigation: `edit add delete | edit add delete` - one is for FORM the other one after " | " is for inline

Comment: @Elen: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You ask about the option which allows to specify Add and Edit buttons for inline editing mode only (in `inlineNav`). The usage of [navSeparatorAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons#separator) is possible of cause, for example you can call it between the call of `navGrid` and the call of `inlineNav` or after call of `inlineNav` and before call of your other custom buttons with respect of `navButtonAdd`.

Comment: I meant - in the same way you took `navOptions` from `jqGrid("navGrid")` into actual grid definition, exactly the same way to take `inlineNavOptions` out of `jqGrid("inlineNav")` into the grid definition

Comment: to add a custom button will stay the same: `.jqGrid("navGrid")
  .jqGrid("inlineNav")
  .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pagerIdSelector, {...});`

Comment: @Elen: OK, I understand. Introducing of `inlineNavOptions` is one more possibility, but currently there are some *common* options like `editicon`, `addicon`, `saveicon`, `iconsOverText`, `position` which are common for `navGrid`, `inlineNav`, `navButtonAdd` and the `formatter: "actions"`. On the other side the `formatter: "actions"` **combines** `navOptions` with optional `actionsNavOptions`. Probably one can do the same with `inlineNavOptions`. Thank you for the discussion. I'll do this.

Comment: @Elen: I posted [the changed](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/0c3dedfa9acbacb4c75948936860ee16e1f6ef64) just now to GitHub. The new sources supports `inlineNavOptions` option of jqGrid.

Comment: thanks Oleg - works fine! by the way, in your comment on GitHub " without additional options will don't add Add and Edit buttons" it's either "will not add" or "doesn't add" (but when tested, it actually does add them if not specified `add: false, edit: false`)